# Change path url language

Tags: multistore, magento-1, language, paths

Currently my domain when switchable in English is

> www.mydomain.com/?___store=en&___from_store=it

I wish it was www.mydomain.com/en

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to admin 
**system > Configuration > General > Web > Url options > Add Store Code to Urls** 
set it to yes

[image]